# Spread operator in object condition on it existing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following Object that make use of the spread operator in ES6:

```
{
  index: {
    ...builderVal,
    choices: {
      ...builderVal.choices,
      [field.key]: {
        ...builderVal.choices[field.key],
        choice: e.target.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `field.key` is a computed value, it may be `0` or `1` or any positive integer number while `builderVal` acts like a local state dictionary. This code works for the most part except when `builderVal.choices` doesn't yet exist (for example, on an initialization, or on first mount).

Notice that on first mount, `...builderVal.choices` would be `undefined` and so up to the fifth line of code no exception would throw up. But on the seventh line of code, because `...builderVal.choices` is `undefined`, the following line:

```
...builderVal.choices[field.key]
```

Will result in the error (assuming `field.key` is 0):

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

So my initial thought, being very new to JavaScript is to use like a ternary operator or an AND operator to first check that it exist, something like (pseudo-code):

```
{
  // truncated 
  [field.key]: {
        builderVal.choices && ...builderVal.choices[field.key],
        choice: e.target.value
      }
}
```

But this obviously don't work. Anything that point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `...(builderVal.choices[field.key] || {})`? But maybe you shouldn't be smashing it all into one expression.

Comment: what about using the optional chaining operator `?.` to avoid the undefined property issue

Comment: Spread syntax is not an operator, it's part of the object literal syntax - you cannot put it in the middle of any expression.

Comment: georg's answer below is the right solution. @jonrsharpe's answer also works as well as charmful0x's. The key lesson for me was the how spread could be applied with a `...(expression)` syntax which was new to me, but `?.` looks more succinct, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the spread to the whole thing:

```
 [field.key]: {
        ...(builderVal.choices && builderVal.choices[field.key]),
        choice: e.target.value
      }
```

or

```
 [field.key]: {
        ...builderVal.choices?.[field.key],
        choice: e.target.value
      }
```

If `builderVal.choices` is undefined, then nothing will be inserted (`...undefined` is a no-op).

Comment: …and as @charmful0x remarked, we can simplify to `...builderVal.choices?.[field.key]`